# Calling back parent function

Tags: c#, oop

I was trying to solve the following problem: I have a Common project and a Specific project. The Specific projects holds a reference to the Common.

I'm creating a instance of a form (from the Common project) and opening it from the Specific one. This form imports objects from a Web Service. In my normal use, I hold the imported object in a property and, when show dialog is ok, I read it normally from the form object.

However, this forces me to close the form. How can I call back the function which is showing the form dialog to process the imported objects while keeping the form open (for further imports)?

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7241093) answer, I tryed to pass the this instance of the class in the Specifc project to the form, but since is holds a reference to the Common project, this causes a circular reference and is not allowed.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very weird scenario you are using. but if I am understanding it correctly there is one project using reference of common project and you are opening on form which is in common project from standard one.

If you want some information from this form without closing it, you can use Event by which you can pass information to the class or project from where this form is being initiated.

hope this will solve your problem

Comment: This Event solution worked. I'm setting a call back object and method, also with a custom Event args to pass my custom arguments and it worked very well. Thanks Nil23

Answer (score 0):

Can you assign your object into to a static property of some other class, so you can access it whenever you want?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you can use [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to deal some heavy task like calling the form and the heavy task could be used **Reflection** to call function from **Common** project.